# Help with Regex expression?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use preg_replace to filter member comments. To filter script and img tags. If src is from my site, allow it with tags, if from another site, just show the src

Regex Expression:

```
  <(\w+).+src=[\x22|'](?![^\x22']+mysite\.com[^\x22']+)([^\x22']+)[\x22|'].*>(?:</\1>)?
```

Using:

```
 preg_replace($pattern, $2, $comment);
```

Comment :

```
Hi look at this!
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg"></img>
<img src="http://mysite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg"></img>
<img src="http://subdomain.mysite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg"/>
<img src="http://www.mysite.fakesite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg"></img>
<img src="http://www.fakesite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg"></img>
<img src="http://fakesite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg"></img>
Which one is your favorite?
```

Wanted Outcome:

```
 Hi look at this!
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg"></img>
<img src="http://mysite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg"></img>
<img src="http://subdomain.mysite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg"/>
http://www.mysite.fakesite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg   (notice that it's just url, because it's not from my site)
http://www.fakesite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg
http://fakesite.com/blah/blah/image.jpg
Which one is your favorite?
```

Anyone see anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to use preg_replace to filter member comments. To filter script and img tags.

[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) is going to be the best tool for this purpose, though you want a *whitelist* of acceptable tags and attributes, not a blacklist of specific harmful tags.

Comment: +1 You'll definitely want to use an existing library; HTML sanitization is a deceptively-complex task (if you're not convinced, there are [already dozens of different exploits circulating out there](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html)).  [Here is a blog post](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2010/08/html-sanitisation-the-devils-in-the-details-and-the-vulnerabilities/) that delves into some of the risks and a comparison of some tools that are available.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing wrong I can see is trying to use regex to modify HTML.

You should use [DOMDOcument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$dom->loadHTML($content);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTag('img') as $element) {

    if ( ! $element->hasAttribute('src')) {
        continue;
    }

    $src = $element->getAttribute('src');

    $elementHost = parse_url($src, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $thisHost = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    if ($elementHost != $thisHost) {
        $element->parentNode->insertBefore($dom->createTextNode($src), $element);
        $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you shoud use im mode;

```
#<(\w+).+src=[\x22|'](?![^\x22']+mysite\.com[^\x22']+)([^\x22']+)[\x22|'].*>(?:</\1>)?#im
```